# Submit to new view in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

I have one controller with an `index()` and a `newFunction()`. When my index function loads, it loads the first view that I need. I have a submit button on that view:

```
<div class="btn"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Pay"></input></div>
```

I want that submit button to load the `newFunction()`, as the new page, right now it is loading the `newFunction()`/view under the index view.

This is what I call in my index function to try and get the new view to load as a new page. Except it loads it right under it.

```
$submit = $this->input->post("submit");
if($submit == "Pay") {
    $this->pay($postData);//pay is the name of newFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->input->post("submit") == "Pay")
    {
        $this->pay($postData);//pay is the name of newFunction();
        return; // With this, rest of the code wont execute.
    }
}
```

Comment: This way i just have to make sure this goes before i load the index/view in the index function correct?